# App doesn't delay with postDelayed()

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I try to make an intro sequence that shows an image, waits for three seconds, then replaces the image with another one, waits for three more seconds and then change layouts to another layout which represents my app's main menu.
I use the method postDelayed to make my app wait.
However, when I run my app it just showes the first image and doesn't do anything else.

Any suggestion why? Thanks in advance

This is the Java code:

```
    //Here is the intro sequence
    introImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.introImg);
    introImg.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            introImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.title);
            Log.w("myApp","replaced image");
        }
    }, 10000); //this will wait 3 seconds and then replace image
    introImg.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
            Log.w("myApp","replaced layout");
        }
    }, 3000); //this will wait 3 seconds and then replace to main menu layout
```

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/introImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/gj_games_android"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code and tell me how it goes.

```
introImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.introImg);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay1 = 3000; // adjust as needed
        final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
        final int delay2 = 3000; // adjust as needed                        // time here is 0


        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                introImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.title);                // time here is 3
                Log.w("myApp","replaced image");

                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);        // time here is 6
                        Log.w("myApp","replaced layout");


                    }
                }, delay2);

            }
        }, delay1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: The way to achieve delays in your code is to use handlers as i suggested. Just use Logcat to see that the first Log.w, gets printed 3 seconds before the second.

Also make sure that after  introImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.introImg);  you set your initial imageresource to the ImageView. (The one you will later change in the first handler).

Comment: Hi, I pasted your code and actually, Logcat doesn't show any of the logs. I also set the initial image resource to the image that already defined in the xml just as you said but it doesn't work

Comment: Check my new answer

Comment: thanks, it worked! The problem was in my code afterwards. Didn't realized postDelayed happens only **AFTER** the other code finishes :) I put the rest of the code inside the Runnable and it worked!

Comment: Nice. Happy to have helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Gili  I have tested the code i provided you and here are the results. i commented out the parts that change the layout as i am only interested in the logs and the time at which they occur. You can see for yourself that every log get's printed 3 seconds after the previous one.

So try it again and tell me how it goes

[image: Test results]